# Something over-riding my web.config when sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web-config

Here is my situation.  We are a manufacturing plant.  When someone submits something to our maintenance department about issues with a machine they have to choose between 2 departments.  The Email has a generic list of recipients but the options send to other people.

The issue I have it that I can change or add/remove the generic email list in the web.config but no change will add or remove people from the optional department email list when selecting a department.  I can't find where it is being overwritten.

This is the aspx.cs form:

```
namespace ContactForm
{
public partial class ContactForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public ContactForm()
    {
    }




    protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            System.Configuration.Configuration config 
                = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(base.Request.ApplicationPath);
            AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection    ("appSettings");

            string emailHost = appSettings.Settings["EmailHost"].Value;
            string fromAddress = appSettings.Settings["FromEmailAddr"].Value;
            string toAddress = appSettings.Settings["ToEmailAddr"].Value;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(emailHost);

            // Default in IIS will be localhost 
            //smtpClient.Host = "localhost";

            //Default port will be 25
            smtpClient.Port = 25;

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.IsBodyHtml = false;
            message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            try
            {
                message.Subject = "Maint Request: " + this.subjectBox.Text;
                message.Body = "From: " + nameBox.Text.Trim() + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Created At: " + txtDate.Text + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Department: " + listDepartment.SelectedItem.Text  + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Priority: " + listPriority.SelectedItem.Text  + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Machine Area: " + txtMachineArea.Text + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Machine Number: " +txtMachineNumber.Text + "\n" + "\n";
                message.Body += "Problem description: " + txtQuestion1.Text;
                toAddress += "allmaintenance@webpage.com";
                if (listDepartment.SelectedItem.Text == "Option1")
                {
                    toAddress += ", user1@webpage.com, user2@webpage.com";
                    //toAddress += ", test@webpage.com";
                }
                else if (listDepartment.SelectedItem.Text == "Option2")
                {
                    toAddress += ", user3@webpage.com";
        //toAddress += ", test@webpage.com";
```

This is the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
            <add value="index.aspx" />
    <add value="index.html" />
    <add value="Default.htm" />
    <add value="Default.asp" />
    <add value="index.htm" />
    <add value="iisstart.htm" />
    <add value="default.aspx" />
  </files>
 </defaultDocument>
 <staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="application/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".oga" mimeType="audio/oga" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
 <add key="MyEmailAddr" value="noreply@webpage.com" />
 <add key="ToEmailAddr" value="Maintenanceusers@webpage.com" />
 <add key="EmailHost" value="mail.webpage.com" />
 <add key="FromEmailAddr" value="noreply@webpage.com" />
</appSettings>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="noreply@webpage.com">
    <network host="mail.webpage.com" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
<!--
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod='SpecifiedPickupDirectory'>
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\maildrop" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>-->
</system.net>
<connectionStrings />
<system.web>
<!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
<compilation debug="true" />
<!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.        -->
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you guys can find anything in here that tells me what is going on and what is overriding any changes I make that would be amazing.  I am in no way a programmer and just took over IT a few months ago and it seems the whole thing was written in C# and need to add some emails to the list

Comment: Since you are not a programmer I have to ask the obvious, are you recompiling the code-behind (the 'aspx.cs file') after you make your changes? I am assuming you are changing the lines 'toAddress += ", user1@webpage.com, user2@webpage.com";' etc. is that correct?

Comment: you are correct.  I have tried adding the emails to the toAddress line under the list selection.  I have tried both options but no matter what I do it will always go to the same people that are on the original cs.  I will even remove them from the cs above but it continues to go to them hen performing a test

Comment: Is this deployed as a ASP.NET 'Web Project' or as a ASP.NET 'Web Application Project'? Where is the file that you are modifying physically located in relation to the compiled code? If this is a ASP.NET Web Application Project then the project would need to be recompiled / redeployed after you change the .cs file. Are you recompining / redeploying after making the code change?

Comment: That's something that I do not know.  I know a good amount of HTML but am more focused on computer hardware and lack heavy in programming.  I don't know how to tell if its a Web App Project or just Web project.  I did not think I would have to redeploy it.  The files for this form are all located in the primary intranet location.  I did not think I would have to recompile and redeploy because we use another form which has its own folder in the directory and all I have to do on that to modify the addresses is open the cs and add the users and save it back onto the server

Comment: In the instance I want to add recipients to the email list for maintenance since all of my maintenance staff get an email I will go in to the web.config file and add the emails I want to put in.  Then I save the Web.config and the changes are applied.  I cant do that in the same fasion when I want to change the recipients when an option is selected (department).  In the other form we use it is done that way.  I will go into the .cs and make the change and it sets automatically which really throws me off

Comment: OK, from that description it sounds like the app you are trying to modify is a web application, which would require a recompile/redeploy, or the .cs file you are modifying is not actually the one being served through the application, i.e. you are modifying a file with the same name but in a different location from where the web site is hosted

Comment: You are correct again.  I managed to find out it is a Web Application.  I am trying to recompile and redeploy but I am only able to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for Web.  The guy before me took the program he was using which was a full Visual Studio.  Can I use IIS to do this with the Web Deploy add on?

Comment: Ok here is what I have found out so far.  In Visual Studio I am able to Build and Rebuild.  I made the changes to the .cs and both Built and Rebuilt but when making the change the only email that is sent is from the first person in my maintenance 'allmaintenance' recipient list going to noreply and says it is a suggestion site error

Comment: Another update.  I have 2 folders in my server.  One for the Intranet and an Intranet backup.  I opened up my backup and without knowing added my email to the recipient list.  I then opened the correct sln and added my name ot th elist but did not work.  I imported the bin folder from the backup folder to the correct folder and it worked.  Everything is working exactly how I want it to.  It is weird however because I cannot rebuild the bin in the Intranet folder.  It has to be rebuilt in the backup folder then moved over.  I also did it without moving over and still got the email error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by finding the web page on the web host server and unmounting the page and re-deploying it with the changes